# making an encryption program and im getting a sytnax error but i dont know why

Tags: java, encryption

Currently i'm trying to make a basic program that takes an input of any string such as a sentence or a paragraph and it takes each letter and turns it into a 3 character code once i get this working i'm assuming i should just be able to do the reverse and have it take the 3 digit code and turn it back to text, anyway i'm getting an error when i try to compile the program to test it. i have the issue marked below. also once i get the program working i would like to make a gui for it where you put in the input and it shows the out put after you click a button but as i am just starting out that seems a but advanced for me if you know any good tutorials for it please let me know!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
class test {
private static Scanner inp;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map <Character, String> encryptionMappings = new HashMap<>();
    encryptionMappings.put('a',"{qaz}");
    encryptionMappings.put('b',"{wsx}");
    encryptionMappings.put('c',"{edc}");
    encryptionMappings.put('d',"{rfv}");
    encryptionMappings.put('e',"{tgb}");
    encryptionMappings.put('f',"{yhn}");
    encryptionMappings.put('g',"{ujm}");
    encryptionMappings.put('h',"{ik,}");
    encryptionMappings.put('i',"{ol>}");
    encryptionMappings.put('j',"{p;?}");
    encryptionMappings.put('k',"{[']}");
    encryptionMappings.put('l',"{qwe}");
    encryptionMappings.put('m',"{asd}");
    encryptionMappings.put('n',"{zxc}");
    encryptionMappings.put('o',"{rty}");
    encryptionMappings.put('p',"{fgh}");
    encryptionMappings.put('q',"{vbn}");
    encryptionMappings.put('r',"{yui}");
    encryptionMappings.put('s',"{hjk}");
    encryptionMappings.put('t',"{nm,}");
    encryptionMappings.put('u',"{iop}");
    encryptionMappings.put('v',"{qaw}");
    encryptionMappings.put('w',"{sxz}");
    encryptionMappings.put('x',"{red}");
    encryptionMappings.put('y',"{cvf}");
    encryptionMappings.put('z',"{ytg}");
    encryptionMappings.put('A',"{hnb}");
    encryptionMappings.put('B',"{iuj}");
    encryptionMappings.put('C',"{kml}");
    encryptionMappings.put('D',"{opl}");
    encryptionMappings.put('E',"{wom}");
    encryptionMappings.put('F',"{wsv}");
    encryptionMappings.put('G',"{ths}");
    encryptionMappings.put('H',"{imv}");
    encryptionMappings.put('I',"{ybf}");
    encryptionMappings.put('J',"{cja}");
    encryptionMappings.put('K',"{thw}");
    encryptionMappings.put('L',"{maz}");
    encryptionMappings.put('M',"{pqa}");
    encryptionMappings.put('N',"{zwl}");
    encryptionMappings.put('O',"{;ld}");
    encryptionMappings.put('P',"{'d;}");
    encryptionMappings.put('Q',"{;ny}");
    encryptionMappings.put('R',"{;ws}");
    encryptionMappings.put('S',"{c/.}");
    encryptionMappings.put('T',"{%@^}");
    encryptionMappings.put('U',"{/mc}");
    encryptionMappings.put('V',"{uka}");
    encryptionMappings.put('W',"{zby}");
    encryptionMappings.put('X',"{&hd}");
    encryptionMappings.put('Y',"{&hw}");
    encryptionMappings.put('Z',"{^#^}");
    encryptionMappings.put('0',"{$g%}");
    encryptionMappings.put('1',"{^@%}");
    encryptionMappings.put('2',"{142}");
    encryptionMappings.put('3',"{243}");
    encryptionMappings.put('4',"{089}");
    encryptionMappings.put('5',"{756}");
    encryptionMappings.put('6',"{423}");
    encryptionMappings.put('7',"{312}");
    encryptionMappings.put('8',"{145}");
    encryptionMappings.put('9',"{187}");
    encryptionMappings.put('~',"{)*(}");
    encryptionMappings.put('`',"{$#%}");
    encryptionMappings.put('!',"{!^#}");
    encryptionMappings.put('@',"{@^&}");
    encryptionMappings.put('#',"{^@&}");
    encryptionMappings.put('$',"{!?*}");
    encryptionMappings.put('%',"{^<+}");
    encryptionMappings.put('^',"{+$$}");
    encryptionMappings.put('&',"{!!*}");
    encryptionMappings.put('*',"{((%}");
    encryptionMappings.put('(',"{*&^}");
    encryptionMappings.put(')',"{$%^}");
    encryptionMappings.put('_',"{&#^}");
    encryptionMappings.put('-',"{<>?}");
    encryptionMappings.put('=',"{:'^}");
    encryptionMappings.put('{',"{%%G}");
    encryptionMappings.put('}',"{$$$}");
    encryptionMappings.put('[',"{***}");
    encryptionMappings.put(']',"{:::}");
    encryptionMappings.put(':',"{#$%}");
    encryptionMappings.put('|',"{?H*}");
    encryptionMappings.put(';',"{B&&}");
    encryptionMappings.put('"',"{@gs}");
    encryptionMappings.put('?',"{^gl}");
    encryptionMappings.put('/',"{@gn}");
    encryptionMappings.put('<',"{%TG}");
    encryptionMappings.put('>',"{5%5}");
    encryptionMappings.put(',',"{yty}");
    encryptionMappings.put('.',"{ggg}");

    inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Password");
    int n = inp.nextInt();

    if(n!=234) {
        System.out.println("Denied Acess");
    } else { 
        System.out.print("Password Accepted"
                + "               ");
    System.out.print("Input Text to encrypt: ");

    String m = inp.next();
    String encryptMe = "He";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
```

The below line is the one that shows a syntax error for "toCharArray" i'm not sure why, I just started learning java so if its something simple that i'm missing i'm sorry, any and all help is apreciated.

```
    for (Character c : encryptMe.toCharArray) {
      builder.append(encryptionMappings.get(c));
    }
    String encrypted = builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you get started. But a hint: this is really basic stuff. In Java objects have fields or methods only. That is why I mentioned to read ALL the javadoc yesterday. Then you would have noticed that toCharArray must be a method call... Thus requires parenthesis. And if quora don't understand that you should study some of the tutorials about these basics first. And I fixed my example code in that answer just now.

Comment: by the way i cant figure out what you assigend the output and input variable to in the code you gave me to me it looks liek "encryptme"is he input and "encrypt" is teh output but when i set it like that it dosn't work and errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on the object but you are missing the empty `()` that need to follow `toCharArray`. Some languages allow you to omit the empty parentheses, but Java is not one of them. You should use:

```
for (Character c : encryptMe.toCharArray()) {
  builder.append(encryptionMappings.get(c));
}
```

A good IDE (Eclipse, Intellij IDEA, Netbeans, etc.) will help you catch these syntax errors as you learn.

Comment: That method is defined in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and I just verified the code works for me. I don't know why you would be getting that error unless there is another one above it. In Java, always try to solve the earliest compilation problem as it will likely impact the following issues.

Comment: i got it working now thanks for the help now i just have to get it to out put the code properly